# Compare/Diff Multiple (>Millions) Arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if this is possible; but I have millions of "lists" in a MySQL database, and would like develop a system where I take one of the lists; and compare it against all of the other lists in the database and return:

1.) Lists that closely resemble the primary list (some sort of % would be great)
2.) Given a certain items in a list; it would return a list of of items that are included in the majority of all the other lists (ie. autocomplete a list based on popular options).

I would've intially thought this would've been possible if I could create some sort of 'loose hash' that I can compare lists mathematically, but I haven't been able to find a solution that scales (since this is exponential when tackled head-on).

Any new ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you describe the data model for your lists?

Comment: Are those lists stored in seperate tables ? Please provide table structure and describe relationships.

Comment: This sounds similar to document comparing, where each list is a document of words. I've gotten good results using tf-idf with cosine similarity.

Comment: Overall, your question is interesting but people will be able to help you more if you provide example rows and database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic MD5 is a (somewhat) loose hash, supported by both php and mysql and quite fast in these kind of things.  Just get an MD5 of what ever data and compare it to others.

Do it in PHP, store the MD5 of the data in array key an use *if isset().*

Comment: Md5 cannot be used for 1) Similarity matching (% match)   2) Finding subset lists.  Both of these seem to be primary requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your part *2) Given a certain items in a list; it would return a list of of items that are included in the majority of all the other lists (ie. autocomplete a list based on popular options).*

is not very clear, but I interpret it as: *Given few items, find all lists that contain all or most of the items*.

This should be easy once you create an index on your list elements, essentially like a hash table. The exact query will depend on your requirement, length of lists (whether that is a factor in defining the specs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying there are millions of lists, itnis really not an option to load them all into a php script.
You could get the values of the list you are comparing the others to, and then run an SQL query similar to this:

```
SELECT list_id, COUNT(value) as c FROM lists WHERE value IN (a,b,c) GROUP BY list_id 
ORDER BY c DESC
```

I'm not sure the sql is correct, but the idea is to select the ids of the lists that have the same members in them and then sort the output by the number of list items that intersect with the original list. The percenage of item correspondence is easily obtained in this case.

Comment: I'm concerned about the similarities in the group of items in the list.  For instance, Recipes table has a million recipes of all sorts of food. I have a the ingredients to make turkey casserole; but I'm not feeling like casserole tonight.  I'd like to be able to find a way, given the list of ingredients in the casserole, for the system to look at all the other recipes and return (in order; by score/percentage if possible) all other recipes that also have similar ingredients (including any casseroles; I'll exclude those later).  I hope that makes more sense.  Thanks!